# .htaccess to get the list of ip from a file or directories of file

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, .htaccess

I'm blocking certain spammers/bots from accessing my website via IP addresses, but I have around 3 directories (/var/www/directory1, /var/www/directory2, /var/www/directory3).

Every time I want to block an IP, I'm required to go into each directory's .htaccess and add the IP address manually.

Is there a way to load the IP address from a file, so that I only need to change 1 place? I tried putting the .htaccess in (/var/www) but it doesn't work.

For context, each of my .htaccess has something like the below

```
<RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require not ip 123.123.123.123
    Require not ip 234.234.234.234
</RequireAll>
```

I want to achieve something like

```
<RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require not ip file_that_contains_list_of_ip
</RequireAll>
```

Or is there any other better solutions for my use case?

*Disclaimers: I can't use softlink/symlinks as the file is slightly different for each directory.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have to use .htaccess? You could use an `Include` directive in the `VirtualHost` section for the websites in Apache's main config otherwise.

Comment: You could also try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47502233/5041163

Comment: Most people don't block the IP-addresses related to abuse manually nor do they do so in their Apache http configuration. They automate the detection of abuse patterns from their log files with [Fail2Ban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban)  and then usually let Fail2Ban block  the offending IP's in a host based firewall rule.

Answer (score 1):

According to Apache's documentation [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when) it seems like it's possible to use one .htaccess from parent directory. 
It may or may not be enabled by default. 
If you have control over Apache configuration you might want to play with those settings mentioned in the doc. 
But be aware that, as doc says, it could impact the performance, as for every hit it'll create additional number of .htaccess files lookups:

> The first of these is performance. When AllowOverride is set to allow the use of .htaccess files, httpd will look in every directory for .htaccess files. Thus, permitting .htaccess files causes a performance hit, whether or not you actually even use them! Also, the .htaccess file is loaded every time a document is requested.
>
> Further note that httpd must look for .htaccess files in all higher-level directories, in order to have a full complement of directives that it must apply. (See section on how directives are applied.) Thus, if a file is requested out of a directory /www/htdocs/example, httpd must look for the following files:
>
> /.htaccess 
> /www/.htaccess 
> /www/htdocs/.htaccess 
> /www/htdocs/example/.htaccess
>
> And so, for each file access out of that directory, there are 4 additional file-system accesses, even if none of those files are present. (Note that this would only be the case if .htaccess files were enabled for /, which is not usually the case.)